# SCJP with label

Tags: java, scjp

Below will be compilation fail due to "label z is missing" but if I just move **z:** to one step below after o = o + 2 then that will work? What is the logic behind this?

```
public class Breaker {
static String o = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
z: 
o = o + 2;
for (int x = 3; x < 8; x++) {
    if (x == 4)
    break;
    if (x == 6)
    break z;
    o = o + x;
}
System.out.println(o);
}
}
```

Comment: read the documentation it clearly explains the same http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: just move `o = o + 2` above `z:`, it should work. because `z` should represent a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put the labels everywhere in the code. it should be only before statements. in this case `labelname: for(;;){}` Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.7)