# Queries on Program with label and jump statement

Tags: java

There is this simple program which has loops and jump statement. I am unable to figure out the output that it is giving.

```
public class Breaker2{
static String o = "";
public static void main(String[] args) {
  z:
  for(int x = 2; x < 7; x++) {
     //System.out.println(o + "  x is this  : " + x);
     if(x==3) continue;
     if(x==5) break z;
     o = o + x;  //2nd question is about this piece of code
  }
  System.out.println(o);
  }
}
```

I am having the following doubts, Sorry if someone finds them simple or silly.

<strike>1. Why cannot I place a Print statement immediately after the jump label (z:)</strike>

1. How is it able to convert from int to string and add/contact the x variable
2. I see that the output 24 comes only by concatenating the values of x. Is it the right conclusion?

Comment: **Why cannot I place a Print statement immediately after the jump label**.. i guess it should work.. can u give an example or error?

Comment: @sanbhat : for example if I add a System.out.println(o); soon after z: .. I get an error pointing to line "if (x==5) break z;" saying label z is missing.

Comment: Got the answer to question 1 from [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666752/scjp-with-label?rq=1)

Comment: I wouldn't call this simple, I'd call it unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson :) Cheerup. I just started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why cannot I place a Print statement immediately after the jump label ?
>   (z:)

When you define a label (like `Z:`), you should define a scope for it (`{}`), and **The scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately contained Statement.** See [JLS 14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

If you write something like this ( please note that i have purposefully removed x from sysout to avoid one more error)

```
        z:
        System.out.println(o + "  x is this  : ");
        for(int x = 2; x < 7; x++) {
            if(x==3) continue;
            if(x==5) break z;
            o = o + x;
        }
```

The scope of z: becomes only sysout statment, and not for loop. to make it work you can define scope with {} like this

```
      z: {
            System.out.println(o + "  x is this  : ");
            for(int x = 2; x < 7; x++) {
                if(x==3) continue;
                if(x==5) break z;
                o = o + x;
            }
        }
```

> - How is it able to convert from int to string and add/contact the x variable
> - I see that the output 24 comes only by concatenating the values of x. Is it the right conclusion?

`o` is a `String` and `o + x` is assigned back to `o`. So the output of `+` operation should be `String`. hence Java converts `x` into `String` (by doing `x.toString()`) and concatenates the content of `o` and `x` to produce `24`

Comment: Perfecto. That answered. Thank u sanbhat

Answer (score 0):

a. Why cannot I place a Print statement immediately after the jump label (z:)

> because label statements can't be labelled, only blocks {} can be labelled.

b. How is it able to convert from int to string and add/contact the x variable

> its overloading operation of '+' which concatenates the
>   objects/primitives when either of parameter is string, it concatenates both the side.

c. I see that the output 24 comes only by concatenating the values of x. Is it the right conclusion?

> yes the result was of concatenation of 
>   o + x

Comment: my 2 & 3 questions are based out of o = o + x ; line of code. not the print statement.

Comment: @sarc of updated the 2nd answer, that clarifies the 3rd also.